# Failed to execute error using Twitterscraper package after compiling with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, hook, pyinstaller

I am using twitterscraper package to scrape tweets. The program works fine on IDE. But when I compile it by pyinstaller, the resulting .exe fails to execute, throwing some error statements on the console.

I have tried using `--hidden-import` and creating a hook file with "hidden import" & "collect_submodule" method to include module used by twitterscraper package. This also failed without any change in error message.

TBH I am noob and don't really understand the nature of the error.

Has anyone encoutered this/similar problem and any idea how to resolve it?

```py
from twitterscraper.query import query_tweets_from_user as gtfu
twitterhandle = '@StackOverflow'
for tweet in gtfu(twitterhandle, limit=20)[:20]:        
    print(tweet.text,'\n',tweet.timestamp)
```

[image: Error Message]

PS: I am using Python 3.6 with Anaconda on Windows7.

Comment: What does this have to do with tkinter?

Comment: @EthanField, I added that tag by mistake (left over in draft from another question). Edited it out.